# Why is this horizontal scrollable table showing extra space on the right side of the table when in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I can't seem to understand why when making the viewport smaller, this responsive table is adding extra whitespace on the right side of it. I've tried using the dev tools to figure out what is doing it but i've had no luck. Below is a code snippet that should show the problem provided the viewport is small enough.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-theme="light">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@picocss/pico@1/css/pico.min.css">
    <title>Test Site</title>
</head>

<body>
    <figure>
        <table role="grid">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" data-tooltip="Position" data-placement="right" style="width: 2rem;"><span class="material-symbols-outlined" style="vertical-align: middle;">leaderboard</span></th>
                    <th scope="col" data-tooltip="Team Name" data-placement="right" class="ladder-header-team-name">Team</th>
                    <th scope="col" data-tooltip="Points" data-placement="right">PTS</th>
                    <th scope="col" data-tooltip="Matches Played" data-placement="right">MP</th>
                    <th scope="col" data-tooltip="Wins" data-placement="right" style="background-color: #77DD77;">W</th>
                    <th scope="col" data-tooltip="Draws" data-placement="right" style="background-color: #FDFD96;">D</th>
                    <th scope="col" data-tooltip="Losses" data-placement="right" style="background-color: #FF6961;">L</th>
                    <th scope="col" data-tooltip="Goals For" data-placement="right">GF</th>
                    <th scope="col" data-tooltip="Goals Against" data-placement="left">GA</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" class="ladder-position">1</th>
                    <td class="ladder-team-name">Team 1</td>
                    <td class="ladder-points">19</td>
                    <td class="ladder-matches-played">9</td>
                    <td class="ladder-wins">6</td>
                    <td class="ladder-draws">1</td>
                    <td class="ladder-losses">2</td>
                    <td class="ladder-goals-for">39</td>
                    <td class="ladder-goals-against">24</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" class="ladder-position">2</th>
                    <td class="ladder-team-name">Team 2</td>
                    <td class="ladder-points">17</td>
                    <td class="ladder-matches-played">9</td>
                    <td class="ladder-wins">5</td>
                    <td class="ladder-draws">2</td>
                    <td class="ladder-losses">2</td>
                    <td class="ladder-goals-for">42</td>
                    <td class="ladder-goals-against">30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" class="ladder-position">3</th>
                    <td class="ladder-team-name">Team 3</td>
                    <td class="ladder-points">14</td>
                    <td class="ladder-matches-played">9</td>
                    <td class="ladder-wins">4</td>
                    <td class="ladder-draws">2</td>
                    <td class="ladder-losses">3</td>
                    <td class="ladder-goals-for">33</td>
                    <td class="ladder-goals-against">29</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" class="ladder-position">4</th>
                    <td class="ladder-team-name">Team 4</td>
                    <td class="ladder-points">13</td>
                    <td class="ladder-matches-played">9</td>
                    <td class="ladder-wins">4</td>
                    <td class="ladder-draws">1</td>
                    <td class="ladder-losses">4</td>
                    <td class="ladder-goals-for">29</td>
                    <td class="ladder-goals-against">37</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" class="ladder-position">5</th>
                    <td class="ladder-team-name">Team 5</td>
                    <td class="ladder-points">12</td>
                    <td class="ladder-matches-played">9</td>
                    <td class="ladder-wins">4</td>
                    <td class="ladder-draws">0</td>
                    <td class="ladder-losses">5</td>
                    <td class="ladder-goals-for">22</td>
                    <td class="ladder-goals-against">41</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </figure>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the `--spacing: 1rem`. If it would be larger it would fill horizontally on mobile. To fix this, just add an `overflow: hidden` to the `table`, like so:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-theme="light">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@picocss/pico@1/css/pico.min.css">
    <title>Test Site</title>
</head>

<body>
    <figure>
        <table role="grid" style="overflow:hidden">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" data-tooltip="Position" data-placement="right" style="width: 2rem;"><span class="material-symbols-outlined" style="vertical-align: middle;">leaderboard</span></th>
                    <th scope="col" data-tooltip="Team Name" data-placement="right" class="ladder-header-team-name">Team</th>
                    <th scope="col" data-tooltip="Points" data-placement="right">PTS</th>
                    <th scope="col" data-tooltip="Matches Played" data-placement="right">MP</th>
                    <th scope="col" data-tooltip="Wins" data-placement="right" style="background-color: #77DD77;">W</th>
                    <th scope="col" data-tooltip="Draws" data-placement="right" style="background-color: #FDFD96;">D</th>
                    <th scope="col" data-tooltip="Losses" data-placement="right" style="background-color: #FF6961;">L</th>
                    <th scope="col" data-tooltip="Goals For" data-placement="right">GF</th>
                    <th scope="col" data-tooltip="Goals Against" data-placement="left">GA</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" class="ladder-position">1</th>
                    <td class="ladder-team-name">Team 1</td>
                    <td class="ladder-points">19</td>
                    <td class="ladder-matches-played">9</td>
                    <td class="ladder-wins">6</td>
                    <td class="ladder-draws">1</td>
                    <td class="ladder-losses">2</td>
                    <td class="ladder-goals-for">39</td>
                    <td class="ladder-goals-against">24</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" class="ladder-position">2</th>
                    <td class="ladder-team-name">Team 2</td>
                    <td class="ladder-points">17</td>
                    <td class="ladder-matches-played">9</td>
                    <td class="ladder-wins">5</td>
                    <td class="ladder-draws">2</td>
                    <td class="ladder-losses">2</td>
                    <td class="ladder-goals-for">42</td>
                    <td class="ladder-goals-against">30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" class="ladder-position">3</th>
                    <td class="ladder-team-name">Team 3</td>
                    <td class="ladder-points">14</td>
                    <td class="ladder-matches-played">9</td>
                    <td class="ladder-wins">4</td>
                    <td class="ladder-draws">2</td>
                    <td class="ladder-losses">3</td>
                    <td class="ladder-goals-for">33</td>
                    <td class="ladder-goals-against">29</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" class="ladder-position">4</th>
                    <td class="ladder-team-name">Team 4</td>
                    <td class="ladder-points">13</td>
                    <td class="ladder-matches-played">9</td>
                    <td class="ladder-wins">4</td>
                    <td class="ladder-draws">1</td>
                    <td class="ladder-losses">4</td>
                    <td class="ladder-goals-for">29</td>
                    <td class="ladder-goals-against">37</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" class="ladder-position">5</th>
                    <td class="ladder-team-name">Team 5</td>
                    <td class="ladder-points">12</td>
                    <td class="ladder-matches-played">9</td>
                    <td class="ladder-wins">4</td>
                    <td class="ladder-draws">0</td>
                    <td class="ladder-losses">5</td>
                    <td class="ladder-goals-for">22</td>
                    <td class="ladder-goals-against">41</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </figure>
</body>

</html>
```